# Looping through a list with selenium

Tags: c#, list, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver

I have a list called dhurl that has 30 web URLs in it. I am trying to loop through selenium web driver code to change the URL every time it loops to perform the same action with a different URL (each URL has a different project in it).

The code I have so far:

For my List:

```
        //Loop which adds keyName and tokenUrl to list
        foreach (JObject item in jArray)
        {
            var keyNameSm = (string)item.SelectToken("keyName");
            var keyName = keyNameSm.Replace("sm-", "");
            var tokenUrl = (string)item.SelectToken("token");
            dhurl.Add("https://" + keyName + ".bewitchedexample.cloud/?sig=" + tokenUrl);
        }
```

My Selenium web driver code:

```
        public void LaunchingDH()
    {
        driver = GetChromeDriver();
        string url = "https://harry.bewitchedexample.cloud/?sig=433435456464546";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("terms-checkbox")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("continue-button")).Click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        driver.Close();
    }
```

The url above in the selenium code ([https://harry.bewitchedexample.cloud/?sig=433435456464546";](https://harry.bewitchedexample.cloud/?sig=433435456464546%22;)) is hard coded and I want to change that URL to dhurl everytime it loops.

The code I have so far:

```
    public void LaunchDH(List<string> dhurl)
    {
        foreach (string url in dhurl)
        {
            driver = GetChromeDriver();
            string url = "https://harry.bewitchedexample.cloud/?sig=433435456464546";
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("terms-checkbox")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("continue-button")).Click();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Taking out the Selenium piece and everything else, the main task here is to pass a item from a `list` into a `string` each loop and perform some Selenium actions on them.

Assuming you have your `list` of URL's ready to go this simplified case below just prints to console, so you can see the results:

```
var url_list = new List<string>()
{
    "URL_1", "URL_2", "URL_3"

};

foreach(string row in url_list)
{
    string url = $"https://{row}";
    Console.WriteLine(url);
}
```

Prints:

```
https://URL_1
https://URL_2
https://URL_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below:

```
JObject URLList = JObject.Parse(@"{
   URLS: [
    {'URLName': 'https://www.google.com/'},
    {'URLName': 'https://www.facebook.com'},
    {'URLName': 'https://uk.yahoo.com/?p=us'},
  ]
}");

var dhurl = new List<string>();
foreach (JObject url in URLList)
    {
        string targetURL = (string)URLList.SelectToken("URLS[url].URLName");
        dhurl.Add(targetURL);
    },
public void LaunchDH(List<string> dhurl)
    {
        foreach (string url in dhurl)
        {
            driver = GetChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("terms-checkbox")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("continue-button")).Click();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
```